# Prove that for any point on the unit circle $\exists t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(\cos(t), \sin(t)) = (x, y)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm being asked to prove this using the continuity of $\sin(t)$ and the identity $\sin(t)^2 + \cos(t)^2 = 1$.

Since the question specifically mentions continuity I was thinking I should divide the unit circle into multiple intervals, then using the extreme and intermediate value theorems to show that it is continuous since $\sin(x)$ has all its maxima/minima and inflection points at $x=\frac{k\pi}{2}$, for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just being two continuous functions satisfying Pythagorean identity isn't enough. What is your exact definition of $\sin, \cos.$ If you define them using the unit circle, $t$ is just the angle between positive $X$-axis and the line through points $(x,y), (0,0).$ If you define them as imaginary and real part of $z=e^{i\theta},$ then any argument of $z$ produce a value for $t$ and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sin (t)$ is continuous, and $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$, $\sin(-\pi/2) = -1$, one can invoke the intermediate value theorem to say that for all real number $y$ with $-1 \le y \le 1$, there exists $t$ satisfying $y = \sin t$. One can proceed to have $x = \pm \cos t$. Also use the property of trig functions: $(-\cos t, \sin t) = (\cos(\pi -t),\sin(\pi -t))$ to avoid the $ x= -\cos t$ case.